# onrecive method i would like to display sender name and date and time

Tags: android

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);


        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );


        if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

        smsList.clear();

        do
        {
            String str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cursor.getString( indexBody );//+"\n"+cursor.getInt( indexDate );
            smsList.add( str );
        }
        while( cursor.moveToNext() );


        ListView smsListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.SMSList );
        smsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList) );
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener( this );
```

Currently I use address column to display SMS sender, so tel number is displayed. I would like to replace tel number with person name. I've expected that person contains it, but it is empty for majority of SMS. Then, date field contains long value, when I would like to show it in the format DD.MM.YYYY